# Java: setting a bool for all instances of a class

Tags: java, class, graph

I searched some times but didn't get a clue.

I'm trying to set up a directed graph. Each node (instance of the `class Node`) should hold a `bool visited` to see if it was visited by a search function.

After the search is completed i want to reset the `bool visited` for all instances of the class without running through them again.

Is there some way i can go - or am I totally on the wrong track?

Thanks for help and cheers,
Mike

```
// Cans.java
public class Cans {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] fillLevels = {2,15,3};
        int[] states = {8,0,0};

        node MyNode = new node(3,0);
        MyNode.setfillLevels(fillLevels);

        node MyLink = new node(3,1);

        MyNode.addLink(MyLink);

        MyNode.setStates(states);

        MyLink.printStates();

        System.out.println("Number of links: "+MyNode.getNumLinks());
    }

    boolean fillState(node nodeA, int stateA,node nodeB, int stateB){
        int value = nodeA.getState(stateA);
        nodeA.setState(stateA, value);
        return true;
    }

}
```

..

```
// node.java
    import java.util.*;

    public class node {
        private int[] states;
        private static int[] fillLevels;
        private int level;
        private int n_nodes;
        private static int id0 = 0;
        private int id;
        private boolean visited;

        List<node> next = new ArrayList<node>();

        node(int n_nodes,int level){
            id=id0;
            id0++;
            this.n_nodes = n_nodes;
            this.level = level;
            states = new int[n_nodes];
            visited = false;
            fillLevels = new int[n_nodes];
        }

        void setfillLevels(int[] fillLevels){
            this.fillLevels = fillLevels;
        }

        void setStates(int[] states){
            this.states = states;
        }   

        void setState(int state, int value){
            states[state] = value;
        }

        int getState(int state){
            return states[state];
        }

        void addLink(node linkedNode){
            next.add(linkedNode);
        }

        boolean isVisited(){
            return visited;
        }

        int getNumLinks(){
            return next.size();
        }

        void printStates(){
            System.out.println("States of node #"+id+" on level "+level+":");
            int cntr = 0;
            for(int i:states){
                System.out.println(cntr+": "+i);
                cntr++; 
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: provide examples of what you've done so far.

Comment: Keep a (static?) collection of nodes as you create them, and iterate over them when you want to reset.

Comment: So basically: You have to go through all instances, there's no other way.

Comment: oh ok. thanks for telling. so ill create a list of elements i visited and reset them when finished.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't add `boolean` flag to the node. It is not a stored property of the node, but a transient property of the algorithm that you are running on it.

Instead, keep a separate set of visited nodes, and pass it around in an additional parameter as you run your algorithm:

```
Set<Node> visited = new HashSet<>();
```

Instead of setting `node.visited = true`, use `visited.add(node)`. Instead of checking `if (node.visited) ...` use `if (visited.contains(node)) ...`

This approach lets you reset all visited "flags" at once by calling `visited.clear()`.

Comment: Thats what i was looking for! Great. Thanks dude.